# PyTorch equivalent of numpy's np.random.RandomState

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I'm looking for a way to create random objects without actually altering the pytorch global seed.

i.e. an equivalent to numpy's:

```
rand_gen = np.random.RandomState(seed)
rand_gen.randint(0, 256, self.image_dim))  # for example
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass your `torch.Generator` manually to the random function.
 I think this code should work:

```
gen0 = torch.Generator()
gen1 = torch.Generator()

gen0 = gen0.manual_seed(0)
gen1 = gen1.manual_seed(1)
torch.rand(5, generator=gen0)
torch.rand(5, generator=gen0)
torch.rand(5, generator=gen1)
torch.rand(5, generator=gen1)

gen0 = gen0.manual_seed(0)
gen1 = gen1.manual_seed(1)
torch.rand(5, generator=gen1)
torch.rand(5, generator=gen1)
torch.rand(5, generator=gen0)
torch.rand(5, generator=gen0)
```